# Source not found page during debugging minidump

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017, minidump

I am developing C++ program in VS2017 and want to fix all bugs which my clients are faced with. I've setup minidump collecting using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps) article. For testing this functionality i create memory access violation bug in my code, start the program, wait for crash and open dump file in VS. All what i want is to see line number where memory access violation occured.

When i do described actions on my machine (i.e. machine where exe was built) all works fine and i can see the line of code with the bug.

But when crash occures on another PC, dumps wont show me line number. Instead VS shows "No Source Found" page to me.

Sure i built exe with pdb files and configured VS as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-dump-files?view=vs-2017), so symbols for my exe are loaded. Also i provided folder with source files in Solution properties dialog.

I am totally disunderstand the cause of this problem. May the problem be in Windows version? I am developing in Windows 7 and another PC has Windows 10.

When i am looking at stacktrace i see the difference after calling something from msvcp140.dll. In dump from my PC msvcp140.dll refers to C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp140.dll, but in dump from another PC it refers to *C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140.dll. Also there is strange msvc_win.dll library which refers to SymbolCache folder.

Also I tried to use WinDbg with the same result: local dumps show line number, dumps from another PC doesn't.

Seems that problem in different Windows or/and MS Visual C++ Redistributable versions.  Because if i copy pdb to another PC and debug dump there with WinDbg it shows me all the things.

Comment: Is another PC windows7 32bit? And if possible, you can try to enable Microsoft Symbol server in visual studio instead of using symbol caches on local environment.

Comment: Both windows are x64. I have deleted symbols cache and downloaded it from Microsoft Symbol Server.